# Retrieve a sorted array of the values from a BST without using additional data structures

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree

I've found answers to a similar question using a List/ArrayList, however my biggest issue is that I am trying not to use any data structures other than arrays. Is there a way to iterate over a BST, adding the value in order to the array?

A little more about the problem - I have a BST that technically is a TreeMap, so it has a `root.value` and `root.index`, both are unique. `root.index` represents the order of the elements addition. I need to return an `int[]` of indexes in ascending order (by `root.value`).

```
    public int[] getDataInOrder( ){
        int[] orderedArray = new int[neededSize];
        getDataInOrder(overallRoot, 0, orderedArray);
        return orderedArray;
    }

    private void getDataInOrder(TreeNode<E> root, int indexOfArray, int[] orderedArray){
        if (root != null){
            getDataInOrder(root.left, indexOfArray, orderedArray);
            orderedArray[indexOfArray] = root.index;
            indexOfArray++;
            getDataInOrder(root.right, indexOfArray, orderedArray);
        }
    }
```

Creating a tree

```
    UniqueIndex<Integer> intTree = new UniqueIndex<>();
    intTree.add(5);
    intTree.add(7);
    intTree.add(-15);
    intTree.add(3);
    intTree.add(1);
    intTree.add(6);
    intTree.add(10);
```

The output should be would be `[2, 4, 3, 0, 5, 1, 6]`, but it is `[0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. I feel like the issue is with the indexOfArray/passing it and updating after adding the element to the array due to the passing by reference, but I can't put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to believe that updating `indexOfArray` inside the method will be seen by the calling method. But Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

Comment: you mean the first getDataInOrder()? It is just a typo, it should start with 0. It won't know anything about updating the ```indexOfArray``` within the overloaded method and I know that. I am struggling make the ```indexOfArray``` update properly for both right and left nodes when iterating

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take the sorted index array out of the function call parameter i.e. not ass it as a parameter and use it in a higher scope. And then keep a variable with the index of the currently filled element in the array.

After that simply perform an in-order traversal and assign the root-index to the next empty slot in the sorted index array and then increment the filled slot counter.

Your error is in passing the array as a function parameter like @RealSkeptic pointed out.

You can do something like this:

```
    private int[] orderedArray = new int[neededSize];
    private int currentElement = 0;

    public int[] getDataInOrder( ){
         getDataInOrder(overallRoot);
         return orderedArray;
    }

    private void getDataInOrder(TreeNode<E> root){
         if (root != null){
           getDataInOrder(root.left);
           orderedArray[currentElement] = root.index;
           currentElement++;
           getDataInOrder(root.right);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I feel like I am missing a key point in recursive approach and returning the value while iterating. How can I assign the values in order to the array that is outside of the method (scope)? If I use a recursive approach I can't figure out how to property do that.

Comment: @I.KK. If you place the array outside recursive method, you are not falling into the pass-by-reference trap that is mentioned in my answer.